# Matlab: Excluding Raw Data From Fit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, raw-data

I'm using Matlab to fit some data using the fit function. By default, `plot(fit, x, y)` plots the fitted curve on top of the raw data. I'm looking for a way to only show the fitted curve. I tried using the outliers feature, but that eliminates data *before* the fit is made, and therefore doesn't work (because I was trying to exclude all data points and therefore fit a curve to no data).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Some code to show what you've done would be nice.  Seeing actual code describes a lot more than what you're trying to convey.

Comment: have you tried... not giving it the `x` and `y` values if you don't want them to plot? (see: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/plot.html )

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following:

1. x and y are your raw data
2. fit is the fit object that contains the curve fit you have done.

In this case, to plot just the curve, you use the following code:
y2 = fit(x);
plot ( x, y2 );